Unit step response of a sampled signal through a LTI system
I have a sampled signal of a continuous time signal say sinusoidal which I want to pass through an LTI system of transfer function 1/s. So I expect a sinusoid as output in continuous time domain. So how can I get the sampled equivalent of continuous time output through this LTI system where I am feeding the sampled signal as input.
In Matlab I am taking a sampled sinusoidal signal and also taking a sampled unit step signal. After that I am convolving both the signals. Is this correct way to get the continuous equivalent of the output as sampled signal (which I am not getting)?
N=20000; %number of samples
f=1000;  %frequency of the signal
fs=80000; %sampling frequency
y=sin(2*pi*f/fs*(0:N-1));
plot(y)
hold on
u_t=ones(1,N);

plot(u_t)
out=conv(u_t,y);
plot(out)


You say you're not getting what you expect, but you're not saying what you do expect.  Perhaps you should edit your question to include your plot of what you get, and describe how it is different from your expectations.
